# Pandas DataFrame to MongoDB via JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, mongodb, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the form

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]],
                      index=['2018-03-27 09:30:00', '2018-03-27 09:31:00'],
                      columns=['UNH', 'V'])
```

I have to convert it to JSON format and then save it to a MongoDB database.
To create the JSON file I run

```
xx = df.to_json(orient='index')
import json
with open('x_try.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(xx, outfile, indent=2)
```

where xx looks like this:

```
'{"2018-03-27 09:30:00":{"UNH":1,"V":2},"2018-03-27 09:31:00":{"UNH":3,"V":4}}'
```

But then when I run (from the Ubuntu terminal)

```
mongoimport --db db_name --collection c_name --file x_try.json
```

I get

```
Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
```

I tried to add the option `--jsonArray` but it is not clear to me where I should add the [...] brackets, as I get

```
Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
```

It's the first time I use mongo and json so I don't know what to try.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? The latest release made some changes to the DataFrame.to_json function, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#json-read-write-round-trippable-with-orient-table)

Comment: I noticed I was still using pandas 0.22.0, I will try now with the latest one.

Comment: I still get the same errors.

Comment: Then it's likely something on the MongoDB side, which I have no idea about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the index in a new column of the pandas dataframe, then using `orient='records'` and by using a simple `.write()` instead of the `json.dump()` function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]],
                  index=['2018-03-27 09:30:00', '2018-03-27 09:31:00'],
                  columns=['UNH', 'V'])
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

xx = df.to_json(orient='records')
with open('xx.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(xx)
```

So that the xx.json file is

```
[{"index":"2018-03-27 09:30:00","UNH":1,"V":2},{"index":"2018-03-27 09:31:00","UNH":3,"V":4}]
```

Then from the Ubuntu terminal I used

```
mongoimport --db db_name --collection c_name --file xx.json --jsonArray
```

and it worked.

I think that one of the possible problems was that `json.dump()` was used on what was already encoded with a json format.